# Mysql query sum values into multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have this

```
id    value
-----!-----
 1      3
 2      3
 1      2
 1      1
```

i have tried using

```
SELECT id,sum(value) FROM table GROUP BY id
```

but it shows something different.

```
   id   ! value
  --------------   
   1        6
   2        3
```

And i want to add values based on their id's but keeping id's there

```
 id   ! value
--------------   
 1      6
 2      3
 1      6
 1      6
```

Please help 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT t.id, q.value
  FROM Table1 t JOIN
(
  SELECT id, SUM(value) value
    FROM Table1
   GROUP BY id
) q ON t.id = q.id
```

Output:

```
| ID | VALUE |
|----|-------|
|  1 |     6 |
|  2 |     3 |
|  1 |     6 |
|  1 |     6 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e1a01/3)** demo

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach would be :

```
select id, (select sum(value) from tbl where id = t1.id) value
from tbl t1
```